# Python Wand - Crop to ratio?

Tags: python, wand

With Imagemagick you could simply do:

```
convert in.png -crop 16:9 out.png
```

At first, I thought

```
Image.transform(crop="16:9")
```

would do the job,
but it just resizes the image to 16x9 pixels, but using aspect ratio in resizing works just fine for some reason.
I can't seem anything else in the documentation either.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What is your question?

Comment: He wants to know how to crop by ratio in Python Wand like one can do in ImageMagick command line. That would be a question for the Eric (the maintainer of Python Wand). I do not see that option within the crop command at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.9/wand/image.html. The OP should identify the version of Python Wand he is using.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the aspect feature was not included for transform crop. Luckily calculating ratios are simple & straight forward.

```py
import math

def calculate_image_aspect(image, width, height):
    geometry_ratio = float(width)
    columns = float(image.width)
    rows = float(image.height)
    image_ratio = columns / rows
    if geometry_ratio >= image_ratio:
        new_width = columns
        new_height = math.floor(rows * image_ratio / geometry_ratio + 0.5) * height
    else:
        new_width = math.floor(columns * geometry_ratio / image_ratio + 0.5) * height
        new_height = rows
    return (int(new_width), int(new_height))
```

Copied from `MagickCore/geometry.c`, but I'm sure there are quicker ways in Python.

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="wizard:") as img:
    new_width, new_height = calculate_image_aspect(img, 16.0, 9.0)
    img.crop(width=new_width, height=new_height)
    img.border('red', 1, 1)
    img.save(filename="wizard.png")
```

[image: wizard.png]

```py
with Image(filename="logo:") as img:
    new_width, new_height = calculate_image_aspect(img, 16.0, 9.0)
    img.crop(width=new_width, height=new_height)
    img.border('red', 1, 1)
    img.save(filename="logo.png")
```

[image: logo.png]